# When to use debug against other logging frameworks

Tags: node.js, logging, express, winston

There are two popular logging frameworks in NodeJS. One is `winston` and another one is `Bunyan`. There is another tool called [`debug`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug).

As far as I understand, they are just doing the same thing which is logging something. `debug` is a default component of an [Express](http://expressjs.com/) app and it looks quite popular based on the number of downloads in NPM.

Can you suggest when to use debug and other logging framework? I am not asking to compare between different logging frameworks. I just wonder the position of `debug`.

Answer (score 0):

`debug` is geared specifically toward interactive debugging. It logs human-readable plaintext and is designed to usually be disabled and then have interesting modules enabled periodically when a developer is actively debugging something. It is also fairly good in both node and browser environments. Its main use seems to be for re-usable libraries as opposed to applications.

`winston`, `bunyan`, and `bole` are geared toward newline-delimited JSON format which is mostly intended to be computer-readable. It's good for applications where your log data is gathered and stored in a central database for later analysis and searching and long-term trending.

So a quick rule of thumb might be `debug` for re-usable packages published to npm and one of the ndjson-format ones for applications where logs are stored long-term and analyzed later.